# How to use related_name of 2 models in 1 Django Template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Hi Djangonauts I am new to Django so please forgive me if there are silly mistakes in my logic or code. I have 4 models. User, Group, Post and Proof.

**User** is just a regular user model

**Groups** are Topics (example: Bicycling, Basketball, Canoeing...)A user chooses which group and writes a Post in that Group.

**Post**: A post is like a "task" which the author shows how to do.(example: how to ride a bicycle on 1 wheel...). The last model is the Proof model where other users respond saying they did what the post explains how to do.

**Proof**: When other users do what the post says. They have 2 upload 2 images click submit and their name gets added to members who did the "task"

Below is my **Proof models.py**

User = get_user_model()

```
class Proof(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='proofmade')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postproofmade')
    made_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    image_of_task= models.ImageField()
    proof_you_made_it = models.ImageField()
    suggestions = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

Below is my post.models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='posts')
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='posts')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True)
    message = models.TextField()
    post_image = models.ImageField()
    made = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='post_made')
```

below is my post_detail view

```
class PostDetail(SelectRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    model = Post
    select_related = ('user', 'group')

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(user__username__iexact=self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

below is my **post_detail Template** (this is where the problem is)

```
{% if user in post.made.all %}
    {% for proof in post.postproofmade.all %} #I know I am referencing the related_name incorrectly. I have tried various options none seem to work 
    <a href="{% url 'proof:proof_delete' slug=post.slug pk=proof.pk %}">
        <img src="{% static 'images/thumbs_up_yes.png' %}" height="25px">
    </a><br/>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'proof:new_proof' slug=post.slug %}">
        <img src="{% static 'images/thumbs_up_no.png' %}" height="25px">
    </a><br/>
{% endif %}
```

I just realized there may be a small problem with this code. If there are 2 people who do the task, the thumbs up image shows 2 times. If 3 people were to do the task. The thumbs up image would show 3 times. I don't want that. The Thumbs up image should show only once.

If user is not one of the members who did the task then it shows correctly. Or if user is anonymous user even then it shows correctly. *(Please see image of the problem below)*.

The thumbs up is a toggle button like a "facebook like" Only that it has a form to add 2 images to prove you did it & delete proof which takes you out of the list of people who did the task. This functionality is working fine

```
{% for user in user.proofmade.all | slice:":1" %} #This gets the job done 
#But I am afraid its not production worthy. I would love a actual solution. If 
#not can someone tell me. What are the bad effects of using this 
#If there are 10,000 people who do the task will the forloop run 
#10,000 times and show just 1 result?
```

[image]
  [image]

Comment: Totally unrelated but this : `<a href="{% url 'proof:proof_delete' slug=post.slug pk=proof.pk %}">` can be a huge problem, unless your `proof_delete` views first shows a confirmation from and only actually deletes anything when the form is POSTed - if it unconditionnally deletes things on a GET query then prepare for some debugging fun...

Comment: @SamirTendulkar as I mentionned this comment was "totally unrelated" - and since your using a `DeleteView` (even if in a somewhat convoluted way - side effects in `get_success_url` is a __very__ bad idea really), the potential issue I mentionned will not happen.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers ha ha I couldn't find another way to get the job done. I am still a noob started Django 1.5 months back. I used the "like" button toggle and somehow inserted my add proof and delete proof to it. It did the job so..

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers `{% for user in user.proofmade.all | slice:":1" %}` This gets the job done But I am afraid its not production worthy. What are the bad effects of using this If there are 10,000 people who do the task will the forloop run 10,000 times and show just 1 result?

Comment: @SamirTendulkar first you shouldn't have mentionned me in your last comment since you're not answering me. Actually this shouldn't even be a comment but an edit to your post. This being said: this will not iterate 10.000 times, that's not how slicing works. But if all you want is to know wheter there's at least one record in the `user.proofmade` queryset, the simple way is `{% if user.proofmade.exists %}`.